# Is IdentityUser.PhoneNumber ignored in the Identity library?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The ASP.NET Identity library appears to have dropped all use of [IdentityUser.PhoneNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1). Is it still used somewhere? Or does it remain solely so it doesn't break any existing apps that use the IdentityUser object?

Comment: Hi @David Thielen, what's the ASP.NET Core version do you use? I check the source code and it exists such property in IdentityUser.

Comment: @Rena I'm on the pre-release version 8 now. But as best I can tell, from version 6 (maybe earlier too) the `PhoneNumber` is no longer used. And the Identity Library no longer supports 2FA using a SMS. Yes `IdentityUser.PhoneNumber` still exists, but I'm guessing that is because removing it would break existing applications. So they ignore it.

Comment: Get your point, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still in use and you can configure it as login requirement in the `Program.cs` like below:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>
(
    options => 
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;
    }
)
```